# Call javascript code after press button and then refresh the page

Tags: php, javascript, html

i'm trying to start a php script after i press a button, and then reload the page, but i have a problem, now i do this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn green big" onclick="startUpdate();">Start Update</a>
```

then this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startUpdate() {
        $.get("Update/startUpdateTxt.php");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

these script write on a txt file, all works perfect but i want refresh the page because i have to change some element and read the change i make in the txt file, so i have tried to do this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function startUpdate() {
        $.get("Update/startUpdateTxt.php");

        return window.location.href=window.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

in this way, the page is refreshed but the phpscript doesn't work anymore, and doesn't write anything in the file, this is the phpscript:

startUpdateTxt.php:

```
<?php
$myFile = "updateStatus.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "StartUpdate\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

how i can do to refresh the page and call in background the phpscript?

Comment: You need to reload the page, only upon completion (success) of the AJAX call

Comment: I am confused.  If you are refreshing the page anyway, why not initiate your PHP script on the server side, before painting the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to make sure that your ajax call finishes. To do that, you could place your redirect in the callback function:

```
function startUpdate() {
    $.get("Update/startUpdateTxt.php", function() {
      location.reload();
    });
}
```

However, it does not really make a lot of sense (to me...) to use ajax to call a php script and then redirect, it would be easier to just post to the php script and handle everything from there.

Comment: what you mean for a better solution? the page that contains the <a href="#" class="btn green big" onclick="startUpdate();">Start Update</a> is a php file, when i press the button i want write on a txt like i do in the startUpdateTxt.php and then refresh the page to reload how i can call a php script when i press the button, if it's this that you mean...

Comment: @Piero You could use a form with a form button instead of a link. Have that form post to your php script and do the processing and redirecting / showing of new html there.

Comment: i have tried your solution, now write in the txt file but doens't refresh the page...

Comment: There is `location.reload()`. I don't know why not just send the result back and update instead of another load (either way I guess). Note, @piero should also use the jQuery event handlers and not inline ones.

Comment: @Piero See the previous comment for the javascript reload or post to your php script and do a `header` redirect from there to your original page. That would save you a request to the server.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thank you i change window.location.href=window.location.href with location.reload() and now works...

Comment: jeroen, I agree with you it's sort've silly to trigger that script then reload the whole page; either POSTBACK w/ `header()` or AJAX w/updated return to update the page.